# UIDatePicker, +/- 1 day difference when used as a string in UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker, nsdatecomponents

I have 2 date pickers, each one deference from the ether (280 day)
the pickers change correctly, but `mydatepicker.date` when NSlog it or put it in`UITextfield` the date become date - 1 day or date + 1 day

here is my code :

the first picker:

```
int daysToAdd = -280;  
// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:daysToAdd];
// create a calendar
NSCalendar *addingdays = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *newDate = [addingdays dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:dueDatePickerView.date options:0];
lastPerPickerView.date = newDate;
 NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

the second one:

```
int daysToAdd2 = 280;  
// set up date components
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:daysToAdd2];
// create a calendar
NSCalendar *addingdays2 = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *newDate2 = [addingdays2 dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:lastPerPickerView.date options:0];
dueDatePickerView.date = newDate2;
NSLog(@"%@",newDate2);
```

if the date of 1st picker is 12-12-2012
the out put is 11-12-2012

in my code i gave them the properity of

```
  lastPerPickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this lines to your code,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

or

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting is correct logically. But if you want the output according to your requirement I think you should change value 280 to 279.

Comment: you are not getting correct answer for any of the date pickers?